# How to Link An iPhone/Android App to Open a Website

Tags: ios, iphone

I am wondering if it's possible and how to have a native iPhone app when opened link to a website (meaning it would open the website) or when opened, there would be a icon to click to have the website open up.

I don't mean a bookmark, I mean an actual app with it's sole purpose to link to a website.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: It's possible. Do you want to open it in the browser, or an embedded Webview?

Comment: Not sure on your intention for the app, but it wouldn't make it into the store. Did you google how to open a URL in the app?

Comment: Such an app would never be approved by Apple. There's no benefit to a user to have a native app that does nothing but bring the user to a website.

Comment: "it's sole purpose to link to a website". If that was its sole purpose it would be rejected by Apple. They even give this as an example of an app that would be rejected. However it is possible using to either launch Safari with the web page, or launch the web page within a UIWebView within your app. So you'd have to specify what it is you want to get a specific answer

Comment: Have you tried `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:yourUrl];` ?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some.web/site"]];
```

**But**, I want to make it clear that *this will never be accepted*:

> I mean an actual app with it's sole purpose to link to a website.

From the [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, unique, **are simply web sites bundled as Apps**, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected